# Issues in cross compiling buildroot for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, linux, ubuntu, arm, buildroot

Facing the issue below while building a custom OS for the Pi 2 using buildroot,
all the configs and everything are going fine .

Whenever I try to compile the image, I'm facing this issue.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi- -j4 zImage
make: arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi-gcc: Command not found
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make: arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi-gcc: Command not found
CHK     include/config/kernel.release
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
/bin/sh: 1: arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/empty.o' failed
make[2]: * [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
scripts/Makefile.build:403: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[1]: * [scripts/mod] Error 2
Makefile:545: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: * [scripts] Error 2**
```

I tried installing ia32-libs but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually installed the cross-compilation tools? If so, you have to add the directory in which they were installed to your PATH. For example:

```
sudo find / -xdev -name arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi-gcc -print
```

will traverse your entire filesystem and tell you where the cross compiler lives. Let's say it printed `/usr/local/fufutos/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi-gcc`. set `PATH=/usr/local/fufutos/bin:$PATH` and try again.

The `-xdev` argument is there so that `find` won't try to look through things like `/dev` or `/proc` and possibly have bad side effects. If you have `/usr`, `/home`, and so on, on different partitions, repeat the `find` command with the root directory of those partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the output - the location of the *gcc is not known to make. To find out where it is installed do a

$ which arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gn­ueabi-gcc

Comment: if `make` doesn't find it, it means it's not in his `PATH`, so `which` is not likely to find it either!